# div CSS not appearing in the html body of email in python flask?

Tags: html, css, email

I am trying to send mail from outlook to another outlook account using the flask.
CSS is being applied to all text part but not to the div part in the HTML body.

I have tried the inline styling also. But it's not working for me.

mail_sent.py contain main SMTP email code

```
def mailfile(smail):
# smail='receiver@ymail.com'
import smtplib
import os
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
fromaddr = "***********8.com"
toaddr = smail
# instance of MIMEMultipart
msg = MIMEMultipart()
# storing the senders email address
msg['From'] = fromaddr
# storing the receivers email address
msg['To'] = toaddr
# storing the subject
msg['Subject'] = "LAN-WLAN Service Hygiene Status"
# string to store the body of the mail
report_file = open('templates/home.html')
html = report_file.read()
img_data = open('****', 'rb').read()

# attach the body with the msg instance
msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
# open the file to be sent
# PATH WHERE FILE IS BEING STORED


# creates SMTP session
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
# start TLS for security
s.starttls()
s.ehlo()
# Authentication
s.login(fromaddr, '************8')
# Converts the Multipart msg into a string
text = msg.as_string()
# sending the mail
s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
# terminating the session
s.quit()
```

Then app.py to run the flask application.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, render_template
import time
from mail_sent import mailfile


app = Flask(__name__)

def mail_sent():
    mailfile("*****")


@app.route('/')
def home():


  return render_template('home.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

In my HTML code I mentioned column width should be 30 % for each, the three-column should appear inline. But, In the mail, the width is 100% and it appears like one after the other sequentially.
Please help me with this CSS problem in HTML in email.

```html
     
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Title</title>
<style>
.col-md-3 {
float: left;
padding: 1px;
margin: 15px;
border-style: outset;
border-radius: 7px;
width: 30%
 height: 100px;
text-align: center;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h7>Greetings!!!</h7>
<p>Please find the Current LAN-WLAN Service Hygiene Status for this week.</p>
<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style = "background-color: Whitesmoke;">

                    <h4>Total Devices</h4>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style = "background-color: #21B01A;">

        <h4>Standard Devices</h4>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style = "background-color: #E65F5D;">

        <h4>Non-Standard Devices</h4>

    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br/>

<p><b>For more details please visit our Hygiene Portal from below link</b></p>
<a>Network Services Hygiene</a>

<p>Regards</p>
<p>Team</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is any of the py relevant to this question?

Comment: Have you tried putting the semicolon after `width`?

Comment: Yes, I with semicolon I have tried, Here I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to open this email in another email software? I've asked because Outlook is known for its weird rendering. There is recommendation for email templates: forget about `<div>`, use `<table>` instead.

Comment: Using table it working but CSS like border and border-radius are not working.

Comment: If you have fixed height of block, you can create background images for table cells -- rectangles with rounded corners. If height is variable, you need to split these rectangles to separate cells.